# remove an iframe from parent from within the iframe itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe in domain-A

```
<iframe id="iframeid" src="domain-B/abc.php"  scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="top: 0%; width:100%;height:100%;left:0;overflow:auto;position: fixed;z-index: 100000;text-align:center;line-height:normal;_position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

The abc.php has a div with cross button as soon as that cross button is clicked I have used jquery to hide the div. The div is removed but the parent page is not clickable (because of iframe)

I want to remove this whole iframe as soon as the cross button is clicked so that the parent page is clickable again.I know its a cross domain issue and I have seen few similar questions but I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible, but i don't have the time to research it. Start here: http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/ It goes on about talking to the iframe from the parent, maybe it works the other way too (iframe to parent).

Comment: I have tried many things nothing has worked so far..

Comment: found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx ... can you get any clue from this?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the parent:

```
function childClose() {
    $('#iframeid').remove();
}
```

Then call this from within the iFrame:

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
$('selector').click(function(){parent.childClose();});
```

But yeah, this wont work if the domain is different.

Comment: This will not work because the parent page is of a different domain than the iframe.